# After SONAR and plug-in upgrades, all false-positives reappeared

Tags: sonarqube

Recently we upgraded our SONAR from 3.x to 4.3. There was an error in our Jenkins build (squidindex was null) which triggered the upgrade of the java from 2.2 to 2.2.1 along with the plugins for JaCoCo, Findbugs, Squid for Java, and Surefire.

Once SonarQube was up and running again, we discovered that although no code changes had taken place, we now had over 200 critical issues as well as a high number of major ones. Upon research, it became apparent that all of our previously marked false-positives had now reappeared.

Obviously we want to find a way to fix this besides walking through over a thousand various issues and re-marking them.

We have done some research in the database and have discovered a puzzle that we think might be related.  In the Issues table, we have found that there are duplicate entries where the first difference is that one entry has the simple file name and the other entry has the file name along with the extension.

*(I had an image of a few lines from the database to put here, but as I do not yet have a 10 reputation, I cannot.  Please contact me and I will be glad to email the image.  Sigh.)*

As you can see, Lines 2 & 3 both refer to line 134 in the file PersistentObjectCollection.java.  Line 2 shows that the issue is FIXED and CLOSED while Line 3 shows the same issue as Open and null resolution.

We are wondering if we could safely use SQL to find matched pairs like this and copy the necessary columns across to register the issues properly?

Can you please take a look and tell me if this is something feasible to do, or if there is a better alternative to try.

Comment: do you solved this issue? .. i've the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

Question already asked on the SonarQube mailing list : http://sonar.markmail.org/thread/kpx3une24lwoilli

Please don't duplicate question !!

Comment: I read stackoverflow but not the sonar email list. Why can't a question be asked in both places?

Comment: Fine.  These are two very different websites.  There is nothing I read in the posting rules that said that the identical people read these and that it was really only one list.  If these are the SAME list, then please make that CLEAR.  I never dreamed that I was only allowed to ask the question one time in the whole web.